# Is there any command that I can learn the size of a table at Hbase?

Tags: hbase

Is there any command that I can learn the size of a table at Hbase?
I use Hbase to hold my crawl data from Nutch.

Answer (score 17):

If you are running hbase on hadoop the following command can be used

```
hadoop fs -du [path]
```

`[path]` has to be replaced with the value of `hbase.rootdir` in `hbase-site.xml`

the output will look like:

> $ hadoop fs -du /hbase

```
4056        hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/-ROOT-

22307       hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/.META.

0           hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/.corrupt

0           hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/.logs

0           hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/.oldlogs

1716        hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/Table1

1472        hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/Table2

1498        hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/Table3

1320        hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/hbase/SampleTable
```

The size displayed here is in bytes.

If you are running hbase on local filesystem (OS filesystem) then you can use normal `du` command.

This will give you a rough idea about size of the table in Hbase.

Comment: How about the data at memory?

Comment: Since the RegionServer which holds the data in memory is a jvm, you can use `jmap -heap <pid>` to view the memory usage. Im not sure whether you can get size of the data corresponding to a particular table in memory.

Comment: Is it possible that this command shows old values? I don't know if I have to compact or something else to see updated sizes, or if I am missing something at insertion.

Comment: Yes true, to get more accurate value we can manually trigger compaction and flush the table before calculating the table size.

Answer (score 1):

To count rows/columns in a table you need to run a map/reduce program. HBase ships with a m/r that does that see [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#rowcounter)