# Command to know the size of a table in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I refered to [Is there any command that I can learn the size of a table at Hbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890223/is-there-any-command-that-i-can-learn-the-size-of-a-table-at-hbase/15929895#15929895) but as a normal user, I don't have access permission to `hdfs dfs -du /hbase` command on`/hbase` directory. Since I have created a table in HBase (say `customer`) and inserted some 100K records, how do I know the size of `customer` table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in a typical hadoop setting you can run hadoop commands as any user.

As such you should be able to do this, as preparation for you file system commands:

```
HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs
```

Naturally you would want to use this with care.

If you are in a secured environment (for instance with kerberos) then this will of course not work.

Comment: I am in kerberos environment and I can run hdfs dfs -ls /user/<my_user_name>/*. Also I can run hbase shell script commands by using kinit command

Comment: @Farooque If you don't have any permission to look in the hbase directory and authentication is enabled, I don't think you can check the table size by yourself. If it is important, consider asking an administrator to 1. Check the table size for you  OR 2. Give you (non-write) permission on the hbase directory. 3. Give you (non-write) permission to the tables you create within the hbase directory

Comment: I am doing READ_EXECUTE here and the permission is hbase:drwx------

Comment: @Farooque That means that only the owner (hbase?) can read, write and execute. (As one would expect by default). As you mention that you are a normal user you should not be able to overcome that limitation by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches, neither great. :)

1)  For a Java Developer, use HBaseAdmin to connect to cluster via a utility.  Something like this

```
   Collection<ServerName> servers=admin.getClusterStatus().getServers()
   for (ServerName serverName: servers) {
       ServerLoad load=admin.getClusterStatus().getLoad(serverName);
        load.getMemstoreSizeInMB();
        load.getStorefileSizeInMB();
   }
```

2)  If you are more of a sysadmin, you can hit the jmx metrics on each region server.  Something like

http://*regionserver*:*regionserverPort*/jmx

and you can grep info like

"Namespace_splice_table_1472_region_a0db9d0ef5e7ae4262bde19a096b2f1f_metric_storeCount" : 1,
 "Namespace_splice_table_1472_region_a0db9d0ef5e7ae4262bde19a096b2f1f_metric_storeFileCount" : 1,   "Namespace_splice_table_1472_region_a0db9d0ef5e7ae4262bde19a096b2f1f_metric_memStoreSize" : 408,
 "Namespace_splice_table_1472_region_a0db9d0ef5e7ae4262bde19a096b2f1f_metric_storeFileSize" : 18908965,

We create our tables at Splice Machine with a namespace splice and a number.  So the table is namespace=splice, table=1472.

Hope this helps, cheers.