# HBase shell command to get the size of a particular table

Tags: linux, hbase

How can I get the size of a particular HBase table from HBase shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any command that I can learn the size of a table at Hbase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890223/is-there-any-command-that-i-can-learn-the-size-of-a-table-at-hbase)

Answer (score 1):

Data present on the hdfs in directory

```
hdfs dfs -ls  /hbase/data/
```

Size of table on the HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -du -h  /hbase/data/<UserName>
```

For Finding Number of Rows in a particular table

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter 'tableName'

counter can be verified from 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper$Counters

OR counter from the Hbase shell
hbase(main):001:0> count 'tablename'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just look into the HBase Documentation

```
count 'tablename', INTERVAL => 100000
```

Comment: Count command returns the number of rows in a table not size.